# How to open Java frame from a web application?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, awt

I am working on Spring based web application and I want open AWT frame for particular request which is given to my web application. How to call this?

Comment: On the server (which is sometimes running in headless mode, and won't be able to launch a GUI) or the client?

Comment: The application will run on server and when the request is coming from client i wont to open java frame in client machine itself.

Comment: The best you can do is (offer to) launch a Java Web Start application (it's a special way of launching a `JFrame`). What is in the frame that cannot be delivered in a standard web app.?